# How do I insert the results from "EXEC()" in a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need som help with a problem, our company have a vendor that deliver a database to us. inside that database, the vendor has a table with alot of t sql scripts. What i want to do is the following, i want to make a select to find the script and then execut the script and store the result in a variable or temp tabel. I can not alter the script from the vedor, so I need the result into something i can manupilate. Another problem is that i dont know how many columns ther result will have. So it has to be flexible. Like one script have 5 columns and and the next script has 8 and so on.

exsample:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = ( Select distinct script_details
from scripttable where .......)
```

This will give me the script I want to use, then I use
EXEC(@SQL) 
to execute the script.

Then my problem is, the result from this I want into a variable or a table.
I have tryed to make a temp table like this:

```
create table #TmpTblSP (col1 varchar(MAX),col2 varchar(MAX),col3 varchar(MAX),col4 varchar(MAX),col5 varchar(MAX),col6 varchar(MAX),col7 varchar(MAX),col8 varchar(MAX),col9 varchar(MAX),col10 varchar(MAX),col11 varchar(MAX),col12 varchar(MAX))
```

then

```
insert into #TmpTblSP
EXEC(@SQL)

This gives me the following error:
Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

But if i know how many columns there are and specify that into the insert it works.

```
insert into #TmpTblSP(Col1,Col2,Col3)
EXEC(@SQL)
```

But here you se my problem, I dont know how many columns there are in every script. I could make one script for every script the vendor has, but that will be alot, it's like 3000 scripts in that table and they change them often.

Comment: In don't know, but you could try if SELECT INTO YourTable EXEC(@SQL) works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = ( 
        Select distinct script_details 
        into #temptbl
        from scripttable where .......
        );

EXEC(@SQL);
```

Comment: Your suggestion only trigger the sql, it does not save the results into a variable or tmp table. Do you know if this it's possible? :)

Comment: Instead of a single table for all the results, will it be OK if there is one table for each of the results. If it is, you may loop through all the scripts and put the results in the respective tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many columns yous @sql gives then the only solution is use SELECT INTO. I use it in this way:

```
    DECLARE @QRY nvarchar(MAX) = ( Select distinct script_details
    from scripttable where .......)

      SET @sql = 'SELECT * into ' + @temptablename + ' FROM (' + @qry + ') A '
```

It gives some flexibility

Remember that it is easy to  check structure of the table created in this way in sys so you can build another @SQL from this info if needed.

I this as well recommended to split "SELECT INTO" to 2 parts
One is

```
SELECT INTO ......... WHERE 1=2
```

Second

```
INSERT INTO SELECT ......
```

Creation of table locks all DB. So it is good to create it as fast as possible and then insert into it.